# PDO SQL-state "00000" but still error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

Can anybody explain why

```
$sql->execute($params);
```

returns `FALSE`, whereas

```
print $pdo->errorCode();
print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
```

both return `SQLSTATE` `00000`, which means according to the documentation success? It is an `INSERT` and nothing is actually being inserted into the database... so, why do I get a success message from `SQLSTATE`?

---

In case it helps, this is the code...

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("
        INSERT INTO user (
            username, fname, pass, salt, email,
            loc_id_home, country_id_home, region_id_home,
            cont_id_home, timestamp_reg, timestamp_upd, timestamp_lastonline, 
            online_status, gender, birthdate
            )
        VALUES (
            :username,:fname,:pass,:random_salt,:email,
            :loc_id_home,:country_id_home,:region_id_home,
            :cont_id_home,'".time()."','".time()."','".time()."',
            1,:gender,:birthdate)
        ");

$params=array(
    ':username'=>$username,
    ':fname'=>$fname,
    ':pass'=>$pass,
    ':random_salt'=>$random_salt,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':loc_id_home'=>$loc_id_home,
    ':country_id_home'=>$country,
    ':region_id_home'=>$region,
    ':cont_id_home'=>$continent,
    ':gender'=>$gender,
    ':birthdate'=>$birthdate
);  

$sql->execute($params);

print $pdo->errorCode();
print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
```

Comment: What you are store in the $params?? please paste it..

Comment: There's a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8759). Maybe this is a reason.

Comment: @JalpeshPatel: thank you, I've posted the code...

Comment: You also need to check `PDOStatement::errorCode` meaning `$sql->errorCode()` after the creation of the prepared statement.

Comment: I know it's old, but I would advise to use $sql->errorInfo(); instead of $pdo->errorInfo();

Comment: Gotta wonder about the logic behind marking this question as a duplicate of a question asked more than 3 YEARS AFTER this one.  This is the better question, with the better title, and more answers. Any idea how that happened @YourCommonSense ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because `$pdo->errorInfo()` refers to the last statement that was successfully executed. Since `$sql->execute()` returns false, then it cannot refer to that statement (either to nothing or to the query before).

As to why `$sql->execute()` returns false, I don't know... either there is a problem with your `$params` array or with your database connection.

> PDO::errorCode — Fetch the SQLSTATE associated with the last operation on the database handle

Note: The PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) does not define exactly what "last operation on the database handle" means, but if there was an issue with binding parameters, that error would have occurred  inside PDO and without any interaction with the database. It is safe to say that if `$pdo->execute()` returns `true`, that `$pdo->errorInfo()` is valid. If `$pdo->execute()` returns `false`, the behavior of `$pdo->errorInfo()` is not explicitly clear from the documentation. If I recall correctly from my experience, execute returns `true`, even if MySQL returned an error, returns `false` if no operation was done. Since the documentation is not specific, it might be db driver specific.

This answer reflects practical experience as of when it was written in September 2012. As a user has pointed out, the documentation does not explicitly reaffirm this interpretation. It also may only reflect the particular database driver implementation, but it should always be true that if `$pdo->execute()` returns `true`, that `$pdo->errorInfo()` is valid.

You might also want to set *PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION* in your connect sequence. Exception handling makes it unnecessary to check and query the error.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't make sense. $pdo->errorInfo() does not refer to the last SUCCESSFULLY executed statment. Simple because it is an error info. It does refer to the _last operation on the database handle_ as given on the php documentation.

Comment: "last operation performed by this database handle" == "last statement that was successfully executed". Performed means completed and a failed statement was not preformed. Try it yourself and note the check mark on the answer.

Comment: The documentation does not say it is a "performed operation". It is just the "last operation on the database" - even if it does not perform and execute() returns false - you can still use errorInfo(). You can try it yourself. Misspell a column name, execute the query (it will return false) and call errorInfo(). Very important is what you check. If you check the overall connection($pdo) it might return no error, but your used query connection($sql) will do. If you use $sql->errorInfo() you get the error.

Comment: @Seb The documentation does say operation. If the parameter array is invalid no operation will be run on the database handle, and no error generated. That edge case should rightly be mentioned in the documentation, or proactively cleared. It is also entirely possible that this behavior has changed since '12, or will change someday.

Comment: Not for this particular query listed, but sometimes the issue arises from the query itself. I had this error occur when I forgot to close a parenthesis in an Insert Query after listing the values.

ex. "INSERT INTO TABLE (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES (...,...,..."            <----Missing ")" caused SQL error

Answer (score 1):

I Faced the similar problem ,

This occurs manly due to **error in query**,  try to **run your query in php-myadmin**  or any other query runner and **confirm** that your **query is working** fine.
Even if our query syntax is correct other simple errors like leaving null or not mentioan a column that  set as  not null in table structure will cause this error.(This was the errror made by me)

As user1122069  explained  the reason for $pdo->errorInfo()  says nothing is wrong may be due to

> $pdo->errorInfo() refers to the last statement that was successfully
>   executed. 
> Since $sql->execute() returns false, then it cannot refer to
>   that statement (either to nothing or to the query before)

Hopes this helps  :)

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to have no error code when execute returns false as people would like to know why it returns false. That this behavior is by design only makes it worse. $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); might give you an idea what's going on as it will throw somthing

Answer (score 1):

From the php manual:

PDO::ERR_NONE (string)
Corresponds to SQLSTATE '00000', meaning that the SQL statement was successfully issued with no errors or warnings. This constant is for your convenience when checking PDO::errorCode() or PDOStatement::errorCode() to determine if an error occurred. You will usually know if this is the case by examining the return code from the method that raised the error condition anyway.

So it sounds like it did insert the record. Check the last record id in your table... maybe you just missed it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error at one time. I only got it on one server for all failures. A different server would report the error correctly for the same errors. That led me to believe it was a MySQL client configuration error. I never solved the specific error, but check your configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check $sql by print_r() and copy your query then try resultant query in phpMyadmin. Hope will get the reason. There would be chance of irrelevant value.